# Load dataframe from json given headers and rowSet

Tags: json, rust, serde, python-polars, rust-polars

I am trying to use the polars rust library to create dataframes from json fetched from stats.nba.com, ([example json](https://pastebin.com/pK1C4x5X)). The best example I could find for creating a dataframe from json was from the [docs](https://docs.rs/polars/0.2.1/polars/frame/ser/json/index.html) but I'm not sure how to load a `serde_json::Value` into a `Cursor` and pass it into the `JsonReader`. Below is my code to load everything into Vecs and then create the Series and DataFrame, but is there a better way?:

```
fn load_dataframe(&self) -> Result<()> {
    let endpoint_json = self.send_request().unwrap();
    let result_sets = endpoint_json["resultSets"].as_array().unwrap();
    for data_set in result_sets {
        let data_set_values = data_set["rowSet"].as_array().unwrap();
        let data_set_headers = data_set["headers"].as_array().unwrap();
        let mut headers_to_values: HashMap<&str, Vec<&Value>> = HashMap::new();
        for (pos, row) in data_set_values.iter().enumerate() {
            if pos == 0 {
                init_columns(&mut headers_to_values, row, data_set_headers);
            } else {
                insert_row_values(&mut headers_to_values, row, data_set_headers);
            }
        }

        let mut df_series: Vec<Series> = Vec::new();
        for (col_name, json_values) in headers_to_values {
            if json_values.is_empty() { continue; }
            let first_val = json_values[0];
            if first_val.is_null() { continue; }
            if first_val.is_i64() {
                let typed_data = json_values.iter().map(|&v| v.as_i64().unwrap_or(0)).collect::<Vec<i64>>();
                df_series.push(Series::new(col_name, typed_data));
            } else if first_val.is_f64()  {
                let typed_data = json_values.iter().map(|&v| v.as_f64().unwrap_or(0.0)).collect::<Vec<f64>>();
                df_series.push(Series::new(col_name, typed_data));
            } else {
                let typed_data = json_values.iter().map(|&v| v.as_str().unwrap_or("")).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
                df_series.push(Series::new(col_name, typed_data));
            }

        }
        let data_set_name = data_set["name"].as_str().unwrap();
        let df = DataFrame::new(df_series)?;
        println!("{} \n{:?}", data_set_name, df);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn init_columns<'a>(headers_to_values: &mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<&'a Value>>, first_row: &'a Value, headers: &'a Vec<Value>) -> () {
    let first_row_array = first_row.as_array().unwrap();
    for (pos, col_val) in first_row_array.iter().enumerate() {
        let col_name = headers[pos].as_str().unwrap();
        headers_to_values.insert(col_name, vec![col_val]);
    }
}

fn insert_row_values<'a>(headers_to_values: &mut HashMap<&'a str, Vec<&'a Value>>, row: &'a Value, headers: &'a Vec<Value>) -> () {
    let row_array = row.as_array().unwrap();
    for (pos, col_val) in row_array.iter().enumerate() {
        let col_name = headers[pos].as_str().unwrap();
        let series_values = headers_to_values.get_mut(col_name).unwrap();
        series_values.push(col_val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/